# replace letters using string.punctuation in a for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

In a nutshell I am trying to replace any punctuation within the words within lines with a space.

For example the text doc output would be without punctuation like this, once processed.

> Meep Meep! I tot I taw a putty tat. I did I did I did taw a putty
>   tat Shsssssssssh I am hunting wabbits Heh Heh Heh Heh Its a
>   fine day to hunt wabbits Heh Heh Heh Stop its wabbit
>   huntin season Huntin Wabbits The finitive guide 101 ways to kook
>   wabbit

Without alteration it looks like this.

Text From question5.txt

> Meep Meep! I tot I taw a putty tat. I did! I did! I did taw a putty
>   tat. Shsssssssssh ... I am hunting wabbits. Heh Heh Heh Heh ... It's a
>   fine day to hunt wabbits! ... Heh Heh Heh ... Stop - it's wabbit
>   huntin season! Huntin Wabbits: The finitive guide 101 ways to kook
>   wabbit.

This is an exercise so i was told to use .replace and a for-loop.

```
import string
infile = open('question5.txt', 'r')

lines = infile.readlines()
lines = str(lines)
for words in lines:
    for letters in words:
        letters.replace(string.punctuation,' ')
        print(letters)
```

Any assistance in fixing the issue would be greatly appreciated.

**Note after your suggestions and some research I ended up after many more hours with this If anyone was following the outcome. Thanks guys *Waves***

```
import string
infile = open('question5.txt', 'r')
lines = infile.readlines()

def word_count(list):
    count = 0
    list = str(list)
    for lines in list:
        list = list.replace('.',' ')
        list = list.replace(',',' ')
        list = list.replace('-',' ')

    split = list.split()
    print (split)
    for words in split:
        count = count + 1
    return count


for line in lines:
    count = word_count(line)
    print(count)
infile.close()
```

Comment: A sorry, I will add some detials

Comment: read 'replace' documentation

Comment: I'm wondering why teachers put these artifical limitations on how homeworks can be made. I mean, programming is about choosing right tools, what are people going to learn if they're told to use wrong tools?

Comment: @thg435: This is just for training the brain. It makes students to understand what happens behind the curtain. The problems from examples was solved many times. The goal is not to solve the problem for someone else. The goal is to understand the way it can be solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is better:

```
import string as st

trans = st.maketrans(st.punctuation, ' '*len(st.punctuation))
with open('question5.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print line.translate(trans)
```

Comment: I picked this because its closest to what i can understand, Im not going to use code if i don't understand it because then its not really my code :D, thanks again

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure as your sample output still include some punctuation - typo maybe?

In Python 2.x, you can try the following as it doesn't actually appear you're replacing with a space, rather than just removing the punctuation.

```
from string import punctuation
with open('question5.txt') as fin:
    test = fin.read()

new_text = test.translate(None, punctuation)
```

Or, using a regular expression:

```
import re
new_text = re.sub('[' + re.escape(punctuation) + ']+', '', test)
```

Example of just using a loop:

```
new_string = ''
for ch in old_string:
    if ch not in punctuation:
        new_string += ch
```

This can be made more efficient by putting `punctuation` in a set (or using the above approaches)

Comment: Hey Jon, Yes my problem is its im not getting the expected result, hence why i'm here

Comment: @bennyboy well you've find the approaches above give you results with no punctuation *at all*

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, as elyase [shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16768403/1346705), you should use the `with` construct, or you should close the file at the end. Also, as he shows, when reading a text file and processing it on the fly, you should never use `.readlines()`. Just for-loop through the content of the file object. It is iterated line by line (including the ending `\n`).

Another problem is with `lines = str(lines)`. Actually, your `lines` is initially a list of strings. The `str` converts it to a single string that looks like `"['Meep...', 'wabits...', 'huntin...']"`. You are looping through that string first -- getting single characters (as single-char strings). Naming it `words` does not change the reality. (If you really want to get the words out of the line, you should use something like `for word in line.split():`.)

Then you are looping second times through the single chars -- getting the single chars again (i.e. the loop turns only once and does not add any functionality).

Next, the `.replace()` *returns the result of replacement*, but it does not modify the argument. You want to *assign* the result to some variable. Anyway, you cannot use the `string.punctuation` as the old string to be replaced as it will never be found in the source text. The brute-force solution must loop through the string of punctuation characters and replace the individual characters.

To summarize, the `letters` still contain the single char -- no replacement. And then you print the single char. The `print` function adds the newline. This way you can see the original content rendered as string representation of the list of strings/lines written the Chinese way -- a single column top/down.

Finally, `the string.punctuation` is just a string constant.

```
>>> import string
>>> string.punctuation
'!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
```

You can simplify your code by not importing the `string` module (if you are not said to do so) and use your own string literal with characters that should be considered punctuation characters.